# How to transfer a string into a JSON in C++?

Tags: c++, json, c++17

In the code, I would like to transform a received std::string with a format like

> xxx:yyy,iii:jjj

into a JSON.
This string is received from clients' side.
I got the error messae as `[json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at line 1, column 2: syntax error while parsing value - invalid literal; last read: 'x'`. The test code is as below.

```
    std::string className;
    std::string instanceId;
    parseUrl(requestUrl, className, instanceId);

    try {
        nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(instanceId);
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "instanceId:: xxx: %s", j["xxx"].get<std::string>().c_str());
    } catch (nlohmann::detail::exception& e) {
        syslog(LOG_ERR, "message: %s", e.what());
    }
```

How could I transform the sting into a so-called raw string or something-else which is acceptable by nlohmann::json::parse().

Comment: That's not valid JSON.  To be JSON, it would have to be `{"xxx":"yyy", "iii":"jjj"}`.  It might be easier to parse your string by hand.  What do you eventually need to do with it?

Comment: To parse the string by hand is the last resort. I need the json data to tell my device driver to do something related.

Comment: If you know in advance that the data looks like a dictionary but is missing the enclosing braces, then you can simply inject braces into the input.  But it looks like there's more problems than just that.  You cannot reasonably expect a JSON parser to handle your input.  Especially not a JSON parser that strives to be "the" JSON parser.

Comment: Nlohmann JSON only works with valid JSON. If you can't received valid JSON from the client, then you need to parse the string another way.

Comment: Perhaps `std::regex` will be sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is not valid json string.

It should be `{"xxx":"yyy", "iii":"jjj"}`.